# Rename Vs Move Ant task

Tags: ant

Actually i am using `<move>` cmd for renaming one folder instead of `<rename>` cmd. but in my case i am moving here 48746 files, so takes 1 approx hour. pls tell me ant appropriate way to rename that folder in optimal way. Thanks in advance.

```
<target name="rename_folder_jet" depends="Upload_on_ftp">
    <move todir="${build.dir}_jet_${ver_number}">
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </move>
</target>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to move/rename the directory only, rather than all its contents. Like this:

```
<target name="rename_folder_jet" depends="Upload_on_ftp">
    <move file="${build.dir}" todir="${build.dir}_jet_${ver_number}"/>
</target>
```

And make sure that the target directory does not exist before you start.

I experimented with the following build file:

```
<project default="rename_folder_jet">
  <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
  <property name="ver_number" value="0.3"/>

  <target name="setup">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/foo"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/bar"/>
  </target>

  <target name="teardown">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}_jet_${ver_number}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="rename_folder_jet">
    <move file="${build.dir}" todir="${build.dir}_jet_${ver_number}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Executing Ant in debug (ant -d) with the above is interesting.

Case 1:

```
ant teardown
ant setup
ant -d
```

In this case, the target directory of the move/rename does not exist. The debug output of Ant shows:

```
 [move] Attempting to rename dir: C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build to C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build_jet_0.3\build
```

Case 2:

```
ant setup
ant
ant setup
ant -d
```

In this case, the target directory exists already on the second execution. The debug output of Ant shows:

```
     [move] Attempting to rename dir: C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build to C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build_jet_0.3\build
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build with patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [] }
     [move] Deleting directory C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build\foo
     [move] Deleting directory C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build\bar
     [move] Deleting directory C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build
```

So it seems that if the target directory does not already exist, Ant will do a *rename* of the directory. But if the target directory exists, it instead does a *copy* into the directory and delete from the source directory instead.

Comment: For me this was moving the whole directory inside the specified todir directory, even when the directory did not exist. I fixed by using tofile instead of todir