# ANT FTP how to rename folder?

Tags: ant, ftp

I'm trying to transfer some files in a tmp dir then rename tmp dir to 'live' dir. It seems ANT FTP does not support directory rename. Any suggestion, work around?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829329/rename-vs-move-ant-task

Comment: This does not work with FTP.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to upload files in a folder or the whole folder?

Comment: The problem I have is that FTP ANT task does not support directory renaming... at least not that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. I did not realise how restricted the ANT [ftp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) was, only a limited range of ftp operations are supported.

The best work-around I can offer is to use an embedded [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) script as follows:

```
<target name="ftp">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>
    <groovy>
        import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

        new FTPClient().with {
            connect "192.168.33.10"
            login "mark", "letmein"
            rename "testdir2", "testdir3"
            disconnect()
        }
    </groovy>
</target>
```

Notes:

- I tested this example with [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html). Had to enable server-side user and write operations before everything worked.
- I've been reading elsewhere that some FTP servers do not support renaming directories.